# Buildroot Cross Compiling GDB Server for MIPS32

Tags: makefile, cross-compiling, buildroot, gdbserver, uclibc

I'm trying to cross compile a version of GDB server from source for the `MIPS32` architecture. I'm using an x86_64 machine.

I'm using the Buildroot `uClibc` compiler for `MIPS` (`mips-buildroot-linux-uclibc-gcc`).

From the GDB server directory I run the `./configure` command:

```
./configure --host=mips-buildroot-linux-uclibc AR=${CROSS}ar LD=${CROSS}ld CC=${CROSS}gcc CXX=${CROSS}g++ RANLIB=${CROSS}ranlib LIBS=-L/root/Desktop/buildroot/buildroot-2018.02.2/output/host/lib
```

With `$CROSS` having the value `mips-buildroot-linux-uclibc-`

`./configure` runs but I noticed in the output it mentions `checking whether we are cross compiling... no`. It doesn't seem like `./configure` is picking up that I'm trying to cross compile.

I then run `make LDFLAGS=-static` which produces the error:

```
ld: cannot find -lthread_db
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:379: recipe for target 'gdbserver' failed
make: *** [gdbserver] Error 1
```

I read that you can remove the `lthread_db` dependencies in the GDB server `makefile` however I need to debug threaded applications.

How can I cross compile GDB server for the `MIPS32` architecture using the Buildroot cross compilation tool set?

Comment: Are you sure that the `--host` option of the `configure` script is not your host PC?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet no, that's --build. However, @CS-Student, you should pass --target=mips-buildroot-linux-uclibc as well. That should fix your `checking whether we are cross compiling...` problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you anyway build the toolchain with Buildroot, the easiest is to also build gdbserver with Buildroot.

- Make sure you have Thread library debugging (`BR2_PTHREAD_DEBUG`) enabled in the toolchain menu.
- Select gdb from Target packages -> Debugging. gdbserver is then selected by default. You don't need full gdb.
- You apparently want a static executable, so select Static only from Build options -> libraries.

This should give you a statically linked gdbserver executable.

Note that if you change the toolchain options (Thread library debugging, static libraries), you have to do a full rebuild with `make clean; make`.